# WebService REST remoto em PHP recebendo JSON via POST com problemas

Tags: php, javascript, web-service, rest, post

Tenho a seguinte situação...

1. Uma aplicação cliente puramente em javascript que roda com o node.js, onde envio via post um JSON, da seguinte forma:

```js
    doLoad = function (livrosList){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://servidor_remoto/webservice/webs.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");  
            arqJson = JSON.stringify(livrosList);

        xmlhttp.send(arqJson);
    }
```

2. Um Webservice em PHP que recebe a lista livrosList e armazena seus dados no banco MySQL:

```php
       include('LivrosList.php');
       header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
       header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

     $obj_php = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['arqJson']));       
     if(empty($_POST['arqJson'])){
        return;
     }

    $livros = new Livros;

    foreach ( $obj_php as $liv ) { 
        $livros->insertLivros($liv->nome, $liv->numeropaginas);
    }
```

O problema é que o $_POST['arqJson'] não está sendo reconhecido. Vejo que no Log do apache está ocorrendo que arqJson não está definido. Não sei se pelo fato de estar em um servidor remoto.
Sendo assim, como eu poderia enviar essa lista de dados para o webservice e armazenar tais dados no banco?
Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O problema é que o WebService está enviando o POST com o `Content-Type: application/json` e o PHP não preenche `$_POST` com os dados enviados dessa forma.

`$_POST` só será automaticamente preenchida caso o `Content-Type` seja `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ou `multipart/form-data`.

Para ler os objetos recebidos neste POST você deve fazer do seguinte modo:

```php
// lê o json diretamente dos dados enviados no POST (input)
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj_php = json_decode($json); // $obj_php agora é exatamente o objeto/array enviado pelo servidor

$livros = new Livros;

foreach ( $obj_php as $liv ) { 
    $livros->insertLivros($liv->nome, $liv->numeropaginas);
}
```

Já quebrei muito a cabeça com este mesmo problema. Espero que ajude!

Comment: Muiiiito Obrigada, o problema era exatamente esse. Funcionou!!