# Buscar dados de uma tabela SQLite em forma de JSON e enviar WebService

Tags: php, web-service, sqlite

Bom dia pessoal, estou neste problema há alguns dias... eu sei como enviar um item do SQLite para o WebService, mas como faço para enviar uma tabela inteira de uma vez?

Cenário:
O usuário faz uma contagem de estoque e vai adicionando itens, na tela existe um botão que busca todos os itens e os envia para o WebService. Os itens não são adicionados acho que meu JSON esta errado (falta uma chave no inicio com o nome da tabela, não sei como faz para fazer isso).

JSON:

```
[{"IdAgendamento":"2","Filial":"1","CodigoProduto":"3","CodigoAlmox":"0","QuantidadeContada":"7","DataHoraContagem":"30-08-2019-17:53:07","SemAgendamento":"true"},{"IdAgendamento":"2","Filial":"1","CodigoProduto":"4","CodigoAlmox":"0","QuantidadeContada":"7","DataHoraContagem":"02-09-2019-10:34:02","SemAgendamento":"true"}]
```

No lado do PHP não sei como fazer para buscar os valores de cada item já tentei de várias formas...

Código PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$response["erro"] = false;


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $itens = $_POST;

    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

    print_r($itens);

    foreach ($itens as $key => $value) {
        $idAgendamento = $_POST["idAgendamento"];
        $Filial = $_POST["filial"];
        $CodigoProduto = $_POST["codigoProduto"];
        $CodigoAlmox = $_POST["codigoAlmox"];
        $Quantidade = $_POST["quantidadeContada"];
        $DataHoraContagem = $_POST["dataHoraContagem"];
        $SemAgendamento = $_POST["semAgendamento"];


        $values[] = "('$idAgendamento', '$Filial', '$CodigoProduto', '$CodigoAlmox', '$Quantidade', '$DataHoraContagem', '$SemAgendamento')";

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (idAgendamento, Filial, CodigoProduto, CodigoAlmox, Quantidade, DataHoraContagem, SemAgendamento)
        VALUES '.implode(PHP_EOL.', ', $values);

    }

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
     {
            echo "Sucesso";         
      } else {

            echo "Erro ".$sql;
      }

    mysqli_close($con);


} else {

  echo "Acesso Negado";
}

?>
```

onBackground do serviço:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(STRING_URL);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //String json = new Gson().toJson(jsonArrays);

            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            printStream.println(jsonArrays);

            connection.connect();
            connection.getResponseCode();
            connection.getResponseMessage();


            String jsonDeResposta;

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)) {
                jsonDeResposta = "sucesso";
            } else {

                jsonDeResposta = "falhou";
            }

            return jsonDeResposta;
```

OBS: Utilizando o Postman e colocando parâmetros (1 item) ele adiciona 7 itens, que é o numero de colunas da tabela não o numero de itens.Se tento adicionar pelo emulador ele não adiciona nenhum na tabela.

@Edit: Refiz o AsyncTask, não estava passando nenhum valor.
public class WebClient extends AsyncTask {
    Handler handler = new Handler();

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(JSONArray... jsonArrays) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        String json = new Gson().toJson(jsonArrays);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        //TODO Inserir site para envio do JSON da tabela "ProdutoQuantidade"
        String url = "SERVER_URL";
        //TODO Tentar utilizar:
        //HttpURLConnection urlConnection = getConnection(url);
        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder.url(url);
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);
        builder.post(body);

        Request request = builder.build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String jsonDeResposta = response.body().string();
            return jsonDeResposta;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "falhou";
        }
  }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$response["erro"] = false;


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $itens = $_POST;

    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");



    foreach ($itens as $key => $value) {
        $idAgendamento = $_POST["idAgendamento"];
        $Filial = $_POST["filial"];
        $CodigoProduto = $_POST["codigoProduto"];
        $CodigoAlmox = $_POST["codigoAlmox"];
        $Quantidade = $_POST["quantidadeContada"];
        $DataHoraContagem = $_POST["dataHoraContagem"];
        $SemAgendamento = $_POST["semAgendamento"];


        $values[] = "('$idAgendamento', '$Filial', '$CodigoProduto', '$CodigoAlmox', '$Quantidade', '$DataHoraContagem', '$SemAgendamento')";

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (idAgendamento, Filial, CodigoProduto, CodigoAlmox, Quantidade, DataHoraContagem, SemAgendamento)
        VALUES '.implode(PHP_EOL.', ', $values);

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        {
            echo "Sucesso";         
        } else {

            echo "Erro ".$sql;
        }

    }



    mysqli_close($con);


} else {

  echo "Acesso Negado";
}

?>
```

Pelo Postman adiciona vários Itens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de 4 dias de busca apresento a solução:

Código PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$response["erro"] = false;


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Busca o JSON passado via POST pelo app
    $itens = file_get_contents('php://input');

    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

    //Converte o JSON em Array de objetos
    $array_obj = json_decode($itens);

    //conta quantidade de registros
    $qtd_itens = count($array_obj);


    for ($i = 0; $i<$qtd_itens; $i++) {
        $idAgendamento = $array_obj[$i]->{'IdAgendamento'};
        $Filial = $array_obj[$i]->{'Filial'};
        $CodigoProduto = $array_obj[$i]->{'CodigoProduto'};
        $CodigoAlmox = $array_obj[$i]->{'CodigoAlmox'};
        $Quantidade = $array_obj[$i]->{'QuantidadeContada'};
        $DataHoraContagem = $array_obj[$i]->{'DataHoraContagem'};
        $SemAgendamento = $array_obj[$i]->{'SemAgendamento'};

        $values[] = "('$idAgendamento', '$Filial', '$CodigoProduto', '$CodigoAlmox', '$Quantidade', '$DataHoraContagem', '$SemAgendamento')";
    }

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (idAgendamento, Filial, CodigoProduto, CodigoAlmox, Quantidade, DataHoraContagem, SemAgendamento)
        VALUES '.implode(PHP_EOL.', ', $values);

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        {
            echo "Sucesso";
        } else {

            echo "Erro ".$sql;
        }

    mysqli_close($con);

} else {

  echo "Acesso Negado";
}

?>
```

Código Java:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(JSONArray... jsonArrays) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    //String json = new Gson().toJson(jsonArrays);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    //TODO Inserir site para envio do JSON da tabela "ProdutoQuantidade"
    String url = "STRING_URL";

    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
    builder.url(url);
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, String.valueOf(jsonArrays[0]));
    builder.post(body);

    Request request = builder.build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String jsonDeResposta = response.body().string();
        return jsonDeResposta;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "falhou";
    }

}
```

Obrigado a todos...

Fontes:

[Como receber dados via POST, enviado do android para webservice PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47921/como-receber-dados-via-post-enviado-do-android-para-webservice-php)

[WebService REST remoto em PHP recebendo JSON via POST com problemas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46949/webservice-rest-remoto-em-php-recebendo-json-via-post-com-problemas/46958#46958)