# Requisição AJAX post com angularjs

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

Olá,

Eu queria saber como eu faço uma requisição `POST` para uma url com o angularJS e também queria saber como eu transformo um objeto javascript normal para um json, para enviar nessa requisição.

Comment: Já viu [essa sessão da documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)? Alguma dúvida específica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o serviço [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) do AngularJS.

1. No seu controller, declare a dependência do serviço `$http`:

   ```
   .controller('TesteCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){ ...
   ```
2. O seu objeto javascript (`jsonObj` neste exemplo) pode ser enviado diretamente. O Angular vai fazer a serialização automaticamente antes de enviá-lo:

   ```
   var jsonObj = { campo1: "teste", campo2 : 123 };

   $http.post('/url-da-requisicao', jsonObj)
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // sucesso! 
     // data agora contém o que foi retornado pelo servidor
     })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // erro!
     // você pode verificar o parâmetro "status" para ver o código HTTP do erro
   });
   ```

Nota:
Por padrão, o `Content-type` do post usado pelo angular é `application/json`. Caso seu servidor esteja usando PHP, você não vai conseguir ler diretamente os dados recebidos em JSON. [Veja aqui uma solução.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46958/20594)

Answer (score 4):

Em AngularJS você pode enviar solicitações de AJAX de diversas formas:

- AJAX calls via the $http service.
- JSONP calls via the $http service.
- REST type calls.

**AngularJS & JSONP**

Exemplo de uma chamada JSONP com a url setada:

```
var url = http://jenkov.com/theService.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK "; 
var responsePromise = $ http.jsonp (url, 
             {params: { 
                   p1: "v1" 
                  ,p2: "v2" 
                } 
              } 
            ); 

responsePromise.success (function (data) { 
    // faz alguma coisa com o objeto JavaScript
    // (no parâmetro "data"). 
});
```

*Estude:* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http