# Dúvidas para implementar um webservice

Tags: php, web-service, libcurl

Tenho uma dúvida quanto a implementação de um webservice, vejam a lógica:

Tenho um processo que busca os dados de vários usuários em um sistema (sistema A), e quero pegar estes dados e enviar para um outro sistema (sistema B), em ambos os casos os sistemas são escritos em PHP.

Dessa forma tenho o seguinte script pra buscar os dados do usuário do sistema A

**arquivo export.php**

```
    <?php
//busca os dados do banco do sistema A   

$r = mysqli_fetch_array($q);

//API Url
$url = 'migracao/import_usuario.php';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

$jsonData = json_encode($r);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonData ))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

No meu outro arquivo, já no sistema B, chamado **import_usuario.php** eu queria receber os dados passados através do CURL para utiliza-lo em um método de inserção dos dados.

**arquivo import_usuario.php**é

```
<?php

new Usuario($usuario); // No caso a variável $usuario seria os dados recebidos atraves CURL
```

O curl esta chamando a pagina corretamente, pois se der um print em import_usuario.php ele é impresso normalmente

A dívida é como receber os dados passados através do curl do php

Comment: Talvez [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46958/20594) te ajude.

Comment: Perfeito André, muito obrigado.

Comment: André Ribeiro, poste a sua resposta como resposta, mesmo que seja o link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução implementada foi a que o andre informou pelo seguinte link:

[WebService REST remoto em PHP recebendo JSON via POST com problemas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46949/webservice-rest-remoto-em-php-recebendo-json-via-post-com-problemas/46958#46958)